# CSV file upload form UI and unable to save content in azure blob

Tags: c#, .net, angular, angular-material, .net-4.8

**In Angualr UI : -**

IN UI application - we just upload an .csv File with 10K rows (in UI just browse the .csv file path and click Upload button)
and from UI below service is being called (FileSaveToBlob) and in the Body of the request complete File name along with blob path will be passed and file content (10K records) will be passed in body.

Please let me know, what mistake I am doing here, file content is not getting saved. And also how do I test my below service in postman, I mean in the request body how do I pass file content, please let me know how to construct request payload for postman.

**This is my service: -**

```
   public class SaveModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the DestinationPath
        /// </summary>
        public string DestinationPath { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Lines
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<string> Lines { get; set; }
    }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("FileSaveToBlob")]
        public IHttpActionResult FileSaveToAzureBlob([FromBody] SaveModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                this.SaveOp(model.DestinationPath, model.Lines);
                return this.Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw this.ConstructHttpResponseException(model, ex);
            }
        }
        

        public void SaveOp(string fileNamewithPath, IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(line);
            }

            var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString());

            this.CreateFileInBlob(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNamewithPath),
                Path.GetFileName(fileNamewithPath),
                new MemoryStream(byteArray));
        }
        
        
        private void CreateFileInBlob(string folderName, string path, HttpContent content)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

            var filePath = string.Format(@"{0}{1}\{2}", this.outputFolder, folderName, fileName);

            using (var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                multipartFormDataContent.Add(content, '"' + "File" + '"', '"' + filePath + '"');

                using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage())
                {
                    req.RequestUri = new Uri("azureblob url");
                    req.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

                    this.traceContextProvider.AttachTraceContext(req);

                    req.Content = multipartFormDataContent;
                    req.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = fileName };

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.basicAuthEncodedCredential))
                    {
                        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + this.basicAuthEncodedCredential);
                    }

                    ValidateHttpResponse(this.httpClientService.SendAsync(req).Result);
                }
            }
        }
```